# Amount of delay in audio signals which are echos of the original audio signal

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, audio, speech-recognition, speech-processing

Could you please inform me, in simulations and also in practical cases how much is delay in audio signals which are echos of the original audio signal (I mean the reference assumption in the literature)? Thanks.

Comment: As answered by charansai, delay value depends on the acoustic environment in which echo is generated. It can vary from tens of milliseconds to hundreds of milliseconds.

Comment: I mean is there any case the echo would be more than 3 seconds? How much it considered for simulations in papers? Thanks.

Comment: yes, it can be around few seconds(depending on Device and Acoustic environment), but to cancel such echo if you want to use adaptive filter directly(without any workaround method) it would be computationally and memory wise expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delay in echo depends normally on Acoustic environment (the physical dimensions, reflective nature of walls, the amount of insulation and so on..)

If your question is "Can we calibrate the delay for a particular acoustic environment?"  I am not sure but algorithms like [these](http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~dpwe/papers/Wang03-shazam.pdf) should be helpful as mentioned by finnw in [this link](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/338/what-methods-can-be-used-to-identify-and-remove-echo-from-an-audio-system?rq=1)