# How can I detect the presence of echo in an audio?

Tags: audio, audio-processing

The presence of echo during a phone call can be extremely irritating. Echo consists typically of the speakers sound being picked up by the microphone with a certain delay (10-200ms). One of the causes of this are low quality headsets (no noise cancellation) or a bad setups (the microphone & speaker are placed too close together).

*My question is following:* **Is it possible to detect echo in an audio recording of only one call party?** (This is a recording of one side of the call but due to the echo, you can hear both sides; the second party with a lower amplitude obviously) **I do not need to cancel the echo, I just want to detect its presence to a certain degree and accordingly recommend a change in the setup.**

*I appreciate any suggestions and hints, thank you in advance :)*

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE, SuperKogito! Maybe you find some ideas in the answers to [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/338/5664) and in the second half of [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/15899/5664).

Comment: @applesoup Thanks for the suggestions, they are quite useful. But from what I can see I would need the target "clean" output signal (which I don't have in my case) for these algorithms? am I missing something?